# \citep problem in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

i am writing a paper on overleaf. everything was going perfect. then i corrected a spelling mistake in the text (not in the code). then problem started.. all the intext citation changed to bold, `\citep` is not working, and references are all gone. i am using compiler **lualatex**
dont know what happened .. please help
here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=1.18in,
            right=1.57in,
            bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\bibliography{ref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}

\emergencystretch=1em
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   
\end{titlepage}

  \clearpage
\newpage
\lhead{Abstract}
\section*{Abstract}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\lhead{}
\pagenumbering{Roman} 
    \setcounter{page}{1}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\newpage
\section*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures} 
\listoffigures

\newpage
\lhead{List of Tables} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables} 
\listoftables
\newpage

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em} 

\lhead{List of abbreviations} 
\section*{List of abbreviations} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of abbreviations} 

\begin{acronym}
 \acro{}
\end{acronym}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
    \setcounter{page}{1}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\section{Introduction} \label{Introduction}

\subsection{section 2}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{subsection}

\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{sub-subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\section{citation \& references}
\lipsum[2]



\section{another section}


\clearpage
\newpage
\section{Reference}
\lhead{}
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=report,title={Reports}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}

\clearpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix A} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Delete all your cached files (click on Logs and output files and choose the trash can icon). Then recompile. The boldface citation means that the reference isn't in your `.bib` file, but it's possible that the compilation stopped early and recompiling will solve the problem.

Comment: not working.. i tried to delete the cache files. but they are still there. and when i'm trying to cite some thing, i can only use \cite{}. but i want to use \citep[]{}

Comment: What does it mean that  "they are still there"? What errors do you get? Also, Is there some reason you need to use the `natbib` option instead of the proper `biblatex` forms `\parencite` and `\textcite`? The `natbib` option is really there to help with backwards compatibility, but its recommended to use the proper `biblatex` commands if possible.

Comment: actually i copied this from another template. could you please tell me where i should do the change? and it working working fine.. but suddenly a simple change created this prob.

Comment: i clicked the logs and output files and then clicked the trash can icon. but logs are still showing.. and the error is "Citation 'xxx' on page 1 undefined on input line xxx"

Comment: You might be faster getting help through the Overleaf helpdesk, where they can see what you're actually doing.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're  compiling your document with LuaLaTeX, you should get rid of the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` statement. Also,do please get rid of the instruction `\usepackage{palatino}`, as its effects are subsequently clobbered by the loading of the `fontspec` package, followed by `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`. Similarly, no need for the `enumerate` package, as you later on load the `enumitem` package.

Comment: thanks for correcting me. i dont know the usage of most of the packages. thanks a bunch